# What is the lifetime of C++ member variables when running in a std::thread?

Tags: c++, c++11, lifetime, stdthread

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

struct safe_thread : public thread
{
    using thread::thread;

    safe_thread& operator=(safe_thread&&) = default;

    ~safe_thread()
    {
        if (joinable())
        {
            join();
        }
    }
};

struct s
{
    safe_thread t;
    std::string text = "for whatever reason, this text will get corrupted";

    s() noexcept
    {
        std::cout << text << '\n'; // it works in constructor as expected
        t = safe_thread{ [this]
                         { long_task(); }};
    }

    void long_task()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << text << '\n'; // the text gets corrupted in here
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    s s;
}
```

In the code above, the `text` variable would print correctly in the constructor. However, in the `long_task()` function running in a separate thread, the text gets corrupted (it outright crashes on another machine). How is that so? If the destructor of `safe_thread` would be run in the destructor of `struct s`, shouldn't the lifetime of `thread` and `text` last equally long? I.e they would both go out of scope when s goes out of scope at `main()`?

Comment: Do you really want to make `s()` `noexcept`? The `std::thread` constructor can throw if the thread could not be started and `std::thread` can throw `std::bad_alloc` if the allocation fails.

Answer (score 11):

Your problem is in the order of declaration member variables inside `s` class.

```
int main()
{
    s s;
    // here is called dtor of S
}
```

When destructor is called data members are destroyed in reverse order of their declarations. You have:

```
safe_thread t; // [2]
std::string text = "for whatever reason, this text will get corrupted"; // [1]
```

so as first string [1] is destroyed, then [2] thread's destructor is invoked and during this invocation your program joins. But then it is accessing destroyed `text` variable. It is UB.

Change the order to be:

```
std::string text = "for whatever reason, this text will get corrupted";
safe_thread t;
```

With this approach, while joining `t`, `text` variable is still visible and not deleted.